# Redirects in htaccess file not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I have an htaccess file with over 700 redirects and most of them are not working at all. I get a 404 page mostly even though they are on the same domain. Here's 5 of them that aren't working:

```
Redirect 301 /orlando-airport/fly-snooze-cruise-hotel-packages-orlando-airport-1-person.html /fly-snooze-cruise/orlando-airport/
Redirect 301 /orlando-airport/fly-snooze-cruise-hotel-packages-orlando-airport-2-people.html /fly-snooze-cruise/orlando-airport/
Redirect 301 /orlando-airport/fly-snooze-cruise-hotel-packages-orlando-airport-3-people.html /fly-snooze-cruise/orlando-airport/
Redirect 301 /orlando-airport/fly-snooze-cruise-hotel-packages-orlando-airport-4-people.html /fly-snooze-cruise/orlando-airport/
Redirect 301 /orlando-airport/fly-snooze-cruise-hotel-packages-orlando-airport-5-people.html /fly-snooze-cruise/orlando-airport/
```

I have checked the domains Please tell me what I am doing wrong. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Do they redirect? Do they redirect to the correct spot? Or do you get a 404 error for the original url?

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one:

```
RewriteRule ^orlando-airport/fly-snooze-cruise-hotel-packages-orlando-airport-\d+-person\.html$ /fly-snooze-cruise/orlando-airport [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This gives a 500 internal server error `RewriteRule ^orlando-airport/americas-best-cocoa-beach/[2-20]-people-fly-snooze-cruise-hotel-package.html$ /fly-snooze-cruise/orlando-airport/americas-best-cocoa/$1-people [R=301,L]`

Comment: That was for 5... Use `\d+`for all values, or `(?:1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20)` for 20 values

Comment: I ended up using `([0-9]+)`. It is a lot shorter and works well. I got the answer from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031996/htaccess-regex-redirecting

Comment: `\d+` is a short for `[0-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out that the rewrite rules in the mod_rewrite section somehow messed with the redirects. So I converted the "Redirect 301"s to Rewrite Rules in mod_rewrite.c and everything is working.

```
RewriteRule ^orlando-airport/fly-snooze-cruise-hotel-packages-orlando-airport-1-person.html$ /fly-snooze-cruise/orlando-airport [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^orlando-airport/fly-snooze-cruise-hotel-packages-orlando-airport-2-people.html$ /fly-snooze-cruise/orlando-airport [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^orlando-airport/fly-snooze-cruise-hotel-packages-orlando-airport-3-people.html$ /fly-snooze-cruise/orlando-airport [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^orlando-airport/fly-snooze-cruise-hotel-packages-orlando-airport-4-people.html$ /fly-snooze-cruise/orlando-airport [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^orlando-airport/fly-snooze-cruise-hotel-packages-orlando-airport-5-people.html$ /fly-snooze-cruise/orlando-airport [R=301,L]
```

Comment: A lesson learned. You should never mix redirects using mod_alias (`Redirect`) and mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`). Since they belong to different modules they don't necessarily run in the order they appear in your .htaccess file, so the results can be unexpected. But these redirects look as if they can be greatly simplified, as @Croises has pointed out.